# How do I explicity tell the user that wi-fi is required for a feature to work?

Tags: usability, interaction-design, user-behavior, user-expectation

So I am designing a product which will have a list of features that affect the mobile device. The features can be split into two categories, one category will work at all times, while the other will work only when connected to wifi. My current wireframe is like this:

[image]

So I'm worried that a text description will not be enough and people will think the bottom settings will work all the time. Is there any clear indicator I can use to show users this feature only works part of the time?

Answer (score 1):

Greying out options is usually the best way to show that an item is unavailable, with the reason why shown right next to it.

[image: example image, iOS: A greyed out "install now" button is followed by a "this update requires at least 20% battery"]